# Cross-origin error when trying to do simple jQuery post to own domain

Tags: jquery, python, facebook, post, flask

I'm doing a simple `$.post` to my Python/flask back-end which is running locally on port 5000.

```
$.post('/g/insert_batch', { data: JSON.stringify(batch)});
```

But am getting these cross-domain errors about Facebook?

`Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://dev.my.origin.com:5000" from accessing a frame with origin "http://staticxx.facebook.com".`

I have `dev.my.origin.com` aliased to `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/hosts` which used to be enough to get me around Facebook complaining about different origins for my local test environment.

I have no idea why it thinks I'm trying to `$.post` to Facebook, and I'm pretty sure this was working just a bit ago without having changed anything.

The only other thing I can think of is that I tested out the Facebook share link on that page which breaks with a 500 server error (this also used to work correctly). I'm very confused as to what could be going on here.

**EDIT:** Figured it out.  I was improperly parsing some of the data I was sending in the post which had a jquery object array instead of the actual data I was trying to extract from it.

Comment: Are you sure that error message is actually related to your `$.post` request?  I think it's common to see messages like that when embedding social buttons, and it's not actually a sign of any problem. Can you confirm that you see these error only when you make a `$.post` request, and that it's not unrelated?

Comment: Nothing in code shown would generate that error

Comment: So I stepped through my code line by line.  After stepping over the post call it immediately errors out (without going to a next line in the code), and all errors point to that line as the originator of the error ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I'll try taking out the facebook share buttons to see if the error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was incorrectly mapping over a jQuery object array, so the data in my batch contained extra data related to jQuery that seems to have been throwing the error.  Changing the data from containing `$inputs.map(input => input.checked)` to `$inputs.get().map(input => input.checked)` solved the problem for me.